# Highcharts: How to add an arrow head at the tip of a connector in a pie chart?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to be able to add a dot at the tip of a connector in a pie highchart. (using Highcharts 5.0.10)

I learned that there are `<marker>` svg elements (not to be confused with the highcharts `marker` api) and these can be added either:

- via `css`
- as an attribute on the `<path>` element.

Although I don't see a way to actually apply them.

I tried appending a marker element during the `render` event in highcharts and then modifying the connector element to add the attribute:

```
render: function() {
  var marker = '<marker xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="circle-marker" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3" orient="auto" viewBox="0 0 10 10">'+
                                                '<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="3" style="stroke: none; fill: red;"/>' +
                                             '</marker>';

           if (!$('#circle-marker').length) {
                 $('defs').append(marker);
           }

           $('.highcharts-data-label-connector').attr('marker-end', 'url(#circle-marker)');
            }
```

Also tried creating a style that would point to that marker.

The more complex part of the issue is I want to make them dynamic (grab the color from the current point).

I might need to get my hands dirtier on SVG (I practically don't know a thing), but also think there is something I am missing from the Highcharts API.

*EDIT:* This is all done inside an AngularJS directive.

[image: dot at the tip of the connector in a pie highchart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Highcharts svg wrapper to create markers and attach them correctly on load event. The issue with the marker is - if you want them to have the same color as the connector,you need to create a separate marker for each - in SVG 1.1 markers do not inherit the color from the objects which refers to them (markers).

```
  load: function () {
    var renderer = this.renderer

    this.series[0].points.forEach((point, i) => {
      var marker = renderer.createElement('marker').add(renderer.defs).attr({
        markerWidth: 10,
        markerHeight: 10,
        refX: 5,
        refY: 5,
        orient: 'auto',
        id: `connector-marker-${i}`
      })

      renderer.circle(5, 5, 5).add(marker).attr({
        fill: point.color
      })

      point.connector.attr({
        'marker-start': `url(#connector-marker-${i})`
      })
    })
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/39xvhwqo/

Comment: Thank you @morganfree! This is awesome. I wasn't that far but this helps a ton. Thanks again.